# Type inference of function as argument in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, function, react-hooks, type-inference

I have case as shown in images below - my function accepts options in form of object with one of arguments being `transform` function. This function accepts `response` argument which type is correctly computed for whole function (first and second picture), but my typescript compiler treat `response` argument implicitly as `any` type (third picture). I can't figure out why it can't correctly assume proper `response` type which should be `ApiResponse<NewsListApiResponseData>` in that case?

[image: First picture]
[image: Second picture]
[image: Third picture]

`Error:(27, 20) TS7006: Parameter 'response' implicitly has an 'any' type.`

Here is my overloaded `useAxios` hook definition for this case:

```js
export function useAxios<ResponseData, TransformedData = false | null | ResponseData>(
    endpoint: string,
    options: {
        autoStart?: boolean;
        transform: (response: ApiResponse<ResponseData>) => TransformedData;
        onResolve?: (data: TransformedData) => void;
        onReject?: (error: Error) => void;
    } & AxiosHookRequestConfig
): {
    loading: boolean;
    canceled: boolean;
    error?: Error;
    response?: AxiosResponse<ApiResponse<ResponseData>>;
    data?: TransformedData;
    request: (config?: AxiosHookRequestConfig) => Promise<TransformedData>;
    cancel: (reason?: string) => void;
};
```

Edit: Added `AxiosHookRequestConfig` definition.

```js
export interface AxiosHookRequestConfig extends Omit<AxiosRequestConfig, 'url' | 'cancelToken'> {
    page?: number;
    lang?: string;
    cache?: boolean | string;
}

export interface AxiosRequestConfig {
  url?: string;
  method?: Method;
  baseURL?: string;
  transformRequest?: AxiosTransformer | AxiosTransformer[];
  transformResponse?: AxiosTransformer | AxiosTransformer[];
  headers?: any;
  params?: any;
  paramsSerializer?: (params: any) => string;
  data?: any;
  timeout?: number;
  withCredentials?: boolean;
  adapter?: AxiosAdapter;
  auth?: AxiosBasicCredentials;
  responseType?: ResponseType;
  xsrfCookieName?: string;
  xsrfHeaderName?: string;
  onUploadProgress?: (progressEvent: any) => void;
  onDownloadProgress?: (progressEvent: any) => void;
  maxContentLength?: number;
  validateStatus?: (status: number) => boolean;
  maxRedirects?: number;
  socketPath?: string | null;
  httpAgent?: any;
  httpsAgent?: any;
  proxy?: AxiosProxyConfig | false;
  cancelToken?: CancelToken;
}
```

Edit2: [Example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=69&pc=4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIAdgCUIGd0D2IuEAPACJxhwB8yA3gFDIvIAmVcAXMpdQDSMAvo0YB6McgDyAN2gAbAnDbIA7sDAALAgFcwyMFDjEYBKAFtGEAB6Eo+mDpAIwwIsh0lU1t7lI58IhI+WgAKZlYIEDZCUDAeXENQAHNBVmQCdFcggH4eJnT0uD0CAGVqezzkACMCAnkIYwBuCMKMkAD6uSrQqDxCYggeDGx+oLIAgeDOGgBKZABeOhkCYDYWtpYiHAArCBce6CgzHgBRKGOoeaXkFbWN1hFZ-NbkRWUUnlr6xpAHlgQxiQDTYXzqDWarw41CqI0m438Y0GIRoLSELQk0jkUHeKnUWgMRhMZksNjsDicLjcIA8Xh8BD88ORnH4yAAKkTcKYLBA2CFFsh4PISMgAD7IEA6eTyMXIJnTag0cLpKIxVbgBJJECpV6ZbLEF6bZDFMBlCpgKrfCF-V7pQzGLkkni9JEkYaYeUTV0QFHXOgch3c8y8kL-QrbPBdCA9aHcdmcoMhzh+26rda21gRvYHZ1HE7Ic6XFN3dPpJ6G1i4z41cG-MOA5wQEFgn6Q9KxqoB4k8vmcNEYyQASXM6AawfAVGpVlsZgpzn1tIg3l8iMCzIE8cDJKT1AFQpF4sl0tlnpRysi0ViGuQiSgKTSrAKmxNZrg9gFhh0EAfbQjuCjAqhCm9BCD+4YdBA2b6AsyBAYsdAgWBdoJiSSGsAAdJhcD0rgUhZNSuCvEIFZtC+5RvhaLbWmGyFbhYPR9GubpoB63qrlMPozCmXaOj2oYZlsEH-vI3TOoxHFSFAITuqMTFenJKKyjxia9tQxZpjRmYQVBhwXPmhZmOp9xEQKIGMM8DCvFW2pUXWrwNsCvK2W2rAdjJnrseMinisp26qXAaKWekfRgDoUA0k+bTWckPD7t+AnIA5TZOYKcDCvFZZoqIcTQPASAFtYcAjg0-KRWomhUBA2I8MYACeggiIwCBBPojFStBi7LgypCnIVxWcYqoQAOT-sGYhhfIQ2smV9rduYPDieM8HIItgzobGDWzC0TUtSteDtQATAKnhLjhPV9aOA1hENYiQIk404lNQWsGR5qxWlJBgbNvHzbBq0kCm-0QOhwC4KUOgIEguC4HBABksN7XJ6HJBAYAhEBm1NEAA)

Comment: Does this code count as a [mcve]?  Can someone drop it into their own IDE and reproduce what you're seeing?  I don't have react dependencies installed on my system so I'll defer to those who do, but my guess is that the definition of `AxiosHookRequestConfig` is probably relevant.  Ideally you'd whittle the issue down to something with no external dependencies at all and then post the code as well as a link to a web IDE (like [the Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/)) that demonstrates it.  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz I've added `AxiosHookRequestConfig` but in my opinion it's not related to the problem. Error comes directly from Typescript compiler, so maybe it could be possible to recreate it in Typescript playground.

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't look related (I wasn't sure if it had its own `transform` property that could interfere).  I'm afraid that without something I can look at in an IDE I don't think I'll have much insight.  Usually in cases like this it comes down to some details for the order and number of various "passes" the compiler takes while doing different types of inference.  If the compiler tries to infer the type of `response` too early or too late, it can be a problem.  You can, of course, manually annotate `response` but it's reasonable to want it inferred.  Oh well, good luck!

Comment: @jcalz I managed to narrow down this case to reproducible demo which shows the exact case when inferring doesn't work as expected - when I add any other property to `options` object other than `transform` (link in post)

Comment: That link doesn't work for me (blank text)

Comment: Should be working now.

Comment: Yep! Yes it is.

Comment: I guess, I made some trivial mistake while trying to properly overload `useAxios` function, but I can't pinpoint it.

Comment: And [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=4&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtVJxwB4AVAPgAoAPALngG94AHGHJuk+AXwEo6A3HFmABuAFChIsBCnTY8BYuWp1GLNhwA0SNGDor4JHvAC8ZeIOHc+FoaLGJCFNa3bwARAAsQAT3fbZPXgqU3MqADoIEFQAcwxPa3ExIA) is what I'd consider a [mcve].

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201115/discussion-between-christopher-kalkhoff-and-jcalz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at what I'd consider the essence of this issue:

```
declare function foo<T>(x: { prop: T }): void;
declare function foo<T>(x: { prop: T, func: (x: T) => void }): void;
foo({ prop: "hey", func: x => x.length }); // error!
//   ┌─────────────────> ~
// Parameter 'x' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

The situation is the same as in [this reported issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13204), marked as "working as intended".  The problem is the call matches the first overload signature, and therefore the compiler can't figure out how to infer the type of `x`.

How does it match both signatures?  The answer is that object types in TypeScript are not [exact](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936).  If you have an interface like `interface Foo {a: string}`, and an interface `interface Bar extends Foo {b: string}`, it is a fact of subtyping that every instance of `Bar` is also a `Foo`.  Meaning that, in general, a type like `{a: string}` is compatible with any object with extra properties in it, as long as it has a string-valued property named `a`.  Often the compiler tries to help people not make mistakes by [warning about excess properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks), but these checks don't seem to happen here since `func` is in one of the types it's checking.  Not sure why, and maybe this is a design limitation or bug.

Anyway, the compiler sees `func` as some function type, but since it's matching the first overload, the contextual typing for `x` doesn't work, and you get that "implicit any" error.

---

There are a few ways to proceed here.  One is to switch the order of overloads around so that the first overload is more restrictive.  A grab-bag overload signature at the top ends up preventing overload resolution from proceeding past it.  That's a good rule in general: more specific overloads at the top, more general overloads at the bottom:

```
declare function foo<T>(x: { prop: T, func: (x: T) => void }): void;
declare function foo<T>(x: { prop: T }): void;
foo({ prop: "hey", func: x => x.length }); // okay
```

That picks the first overload, and the type of `func` is known, and `x` is inferred as `string`.

---

Another way to proceed is to take the more-general overload and change it so it actually prohibits the call in question, by making `func` a property that it can't have, like this:

```
declare function foo<T>(x: { prop: T, func?: never }): void;
declare function foo<T>(x: { prop: T, func: (x: T) => void }): void;
foo({ prop: "hey", func: x => x.length }); // okay
```

That works now because in the first overload, `func` is an optional property whose value is of type `never`.  There's no way other than `undefined` to satisfy that, and a function like `x => x.length` certainly doesn't.  So the call skips the first overload, picks the second, and infers `string` for `x`.

---

Finally, in the case where the two overloads in question are so similar except for a possibly-present property, I'd be inclined to collapse them into a single signature and forget overloads entirely.  This might not match your use case, but it's something to keep in mind:

```
declare function foo<T>(x: { prop: T, func?: (x: T) => void }): void;
foo({ prop: "hey", func: x => x.length }); // okay
```

Now there is only a single call signature, and `func` can be present or absent.

---

One of those should hopefully work for you.  [I've tested the second one on your example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIAdgCUIGd0D2IuEAPACJxhwB8yA3gFDIvIAmVcAXMpdQDTNWwXAGUArgiS5cACgCUPAEYECAGwhwQg1sgDmEMHzgKexxgF9GjAPQ3kAeQBu0NQThtkAd2BgAFgTiYMhgUFq4MARQALaMEAAehFDBMOIgCGDARMjiJKjxWbikOPhEJMY0skIsECBshKBgPLihoHo6rATomWUA-DxMurpwQQSi1Mn9yCrqmiAA3NVDRCXqLlOyUHiExBA8GNjbZWQlO+WcNPLIALx0TgTAbItDnSA4AFYQGRvQUFE8AFEoH8oFdbsh7o9ni8QmFiJEYlMQBAXFBoSwrIoGEs3B42spVBotOjkAgtEgNGwCbNiUsONQpgdTsdikddhVFhZFnZHKjcZ4fP5YeEEbEEkkUmkMlkQDk8gUCEVmezOPxkAAVOERKLRCBsYw3ZDwNQkZAAH2QIHEajU5uQyvO1EqS1q9Qe4GarRA7SWXR6xAGS2Go3GcEm1KJCyDrFCIp1PE2bJI+0wDpOSYgFTBdE1cZieuMJN0KzwawgG3p3A1WtFBc42YhDye0ZYJc+3wTv3+yCBIIbkObukxgd0-Px00JcxJZPSEEpEandM4U1z8J1deonO59gAktF0BpdeAqDK4okopL0v65RB8oVWaUVQJq3ndfrOIbjaaLVabXa0xUVS6K6DQesgLRQG0HQsIMMIjGAYwTME1ywuIEDQcsbylmoLiGgoNx0PQyAWBhxZYe2yHIPh4JESRLbCmuMSkawAB0bFwAquAON0Mq4EsFgjnBIZIVMMyRkWMY1jqGxbI+yZoKmGYPmcmYXA2q7avm76bvRJa4GWMkZg4UDGCmhxyemFkVHaGm1tpcD9k2EmtuRXxgD8wLdr2USOVC-GGvQw7YqO7hsOOYmLroM4UnqC60rolaMopFnKcc1kWrZ672ZywWsFsYDiFAsqwS8Y7ejwX7ofR0VzrFRpwCaVVDpy1iNNA8BID28RwPuGgGiV3h+FQKLQDwWgAJ6CFYjAIGUwSydalG5LenGkAC3W9apTqyAA5Ppuo2IVag7WqA2xox0Q8LJKkEcg13HCxlZTfIiwzXNd14ItABMhrLXeiprRtB5bbQu02JALSHVAx2nUs8GIWGTT1Y1GHnZpl1UfduwNljJAsSIEhSHgchXAAZKTH0WSxBhGJwCjPfMQA), for what it's worth.

Okay, good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=21&ssc=55&pln=20&pc=1#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAFATgewEYBsJiQG8AoJMpAEwnhxDWQDMBXYeAFwEsNgkGMMAPABUAfAAoAHgC4iSGJhgyhSAL4BKGQDcMHCgG5S5KjTqMW7Ljz6DRkmYTkKlAGl7mZdpELVIAvCKRtXVUNQJ19QzJrMQd5DEUkACIACwgAT0TXZlYZCT8AiQA6PGAAczZkkL0kAHoapAg0TDQAQmIVYmJQSFgEZABlDBwmTm4AJQgMNCo0IkjKalp6N1ZRq35hcWlZOIShLPckT298sOD1LXCDcgWTZeyLbl4N223Ypy8Qy91r8mj3+IyFLpTIreC5U5FErlSrqap1JAYADWIDS7U63WgcEQSEGwzWEygbDQHHYcxuxiWZlWlmeNi29kcgK8B1YAH4ZMAIJpGl8zhEKYtTGC1nTNp4AXtWeCjtsTv5+XyggK-vwYkyEsCMtKIQqoRAyhUqrV6sjUeiuuAsX1cUMRpYAMIYMBYDhc8lGIX3cyi6zit4alxgjmypQ+BXKpVXeb-QNJVLasG6grFA0w40Is1olRAA)

Comment: Amazing and incredibly detailed answer! Thanks you so much, that helped me a great deal. I've tried option #3 as a starting point before even asking this question and overloading my function declaration. Unfortunately it didn't work for me because of the implementation details, but both option #1 as well as option #2 works like a charm.